# How to get individual count, and not cumulative, in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am publishing counts to prometheus using Counter variables and the visualization is done in Grafana dashboard. In my application, I am reading from a topic, and after a process is complete, say, to create a customer, the Counter(io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter) variable is increased. As and when the customer is created this variable is incremented.

In Grafana I am able to visualize it as well. But, if I put the range as, say last 15 minutes, Grafana shows the count fine.

[image]

**Question:**
How can I configure that Grafana should show 15:00:00 -> 5 and **15:05:00 -> 5**.

I see we can put the time-interval, and changing that to 5 mins or 10 mins, didn't help me.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the nature of [counters](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter). Regarding your question, you can use query like `increase(my_metric[5m])`

Comment: On the application end, I am not decreasing count of any metric collected, that's the reason I didn't use Gauge. Thanks for the answer, I will try that out.

Comment: I meant, that counter stores cumulative value, and to get only recent change, you'll need something like `increase` function. But based on you comment, I see that I was wrong most likely.

Comment: thanks. I had another question, I will put it here, please help if you can.

Comment: Don't put two questions in one post: it's against the rules of SO, and could be a reason to close the question. Regarding question itself: you need to set [legend](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/query-editor/#legend) to custom value `{{__name__}}`.

Comment: should I remove the edit? I didn't think if this should take a complete new question.

Comment: Yes, remove it. And also, clean up the rest: you have "below is my query:" without query, numerated list with single point, and time in question differs from time in screenshot. Regarding new question: technically it would be allowed, as requests for official documentation are allowed, but I don't believe it would be useful.